# How can I integrate Thunderbird Lightning calendar into the Unity message indicator menu?

Tags: unity, thunderbird, 16.10, calendar, indicator-message

Thunderbird provides [Lightning](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/using-lightning-google-calendar), a proper calendar solution. In analogy to its "Contacts" solution, how can I integrate "Calendar" into the message indicator menu of Ubuntu 16.10 Unity?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Ubuntu's indicator uses evolution-data-server (i.e eds) as backend. You can use eds extension for thunderbird. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/eds-calendar-integration/

Comment: My Thunderbird 45.5.1 crashes upon start after having installed this add-on.

Comment: Probably this iisue: https://github.com/balbusm/xul-ext-eds-calendar/issues/13  if not open a new issue https://github.com/balbusm/xul-ext-eds-calendar/issues/new oh I guess you already did!

Comment: Alternate solution would be to use `gnome-calendar` or `evolution`. Calendar is already installed by default. For evolution try `sudo apt-get install evolution`

Comment: Thank you! I hope we can solve the issue with it. Actually I prefer Thunderbird Lightning. :-)